# Rails Paperclip Error after upgrading ruby from 2.3.1 to 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Existing project is in ruby 2.3.1 and upgrading version to 3.0.1 (rails 6.1.4) with related gems.

Updated gem to "paperclip" to "kt-paperclip".

I am getting following error while upload a document.
Error:
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/RackMultipart20210809-20058-nn1h6f.jpeg to /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-f12xva.jpeg
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-f12xva.jpeg to /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-tr9ezt.jpeg
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-f12xva.jpeg to /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-ddtnlx.jpeg
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-f12xva.jpeg to /tmp/a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c20210809-20058-ux65dm.jpeg

Following is my existing settings:

```
has_attached_file :file_local,
                path: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                url:  "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 

has_attached_file :file,
            processors: [:format_delegator],
            path: ":configured_path",
            whiny: false,
            styles: {rectangle: ["1280x640#", :jpg],
                     narrow: ["640x", :jpg],
                     large: ["1980x", :jpg],
                     square: ["480x480#", :jpg],
                     thumbnail: ["1920x1080#", :jpg],
                     encoded: {output: "html5",
                               processors: [:transcoder]}},             
            default_url: :set_default_url,
            storage: :s3,
            url: SETTINGS[:amazon][:s3_alias_url], 
            s3_host_name: SETTINGS[:amazon][:host_name],
            s3_host_alias: SETTINGS[:amazon][:cloudfront_host],
            s3_permissions: :private,
            s3_protocol: :https,
            s3_region: SETTINGS[:amazon][:region],
            s3_credentials: {
                bucket: SETTINGS[:amazon][:bucket]
            }
```

Any one knows, how to solve above issue?
Which configuration i need to check to track the issue?

Comment: Wow - that's a *lot* of Rails versions to jump past! Did you straight from Rails 2 to Rails 6, or did you go through the versions and check all the changes as you went? FWIW, you may be able to remove Paperclip and use the the ActiveStorage tools that are now in Rails.

Comment: I have updated required gems one by one and also updated related code changes. Except the file upload everything is working as expected. For now, paperclip code is more used so if any way to solve with paperclip i want to go with it. note : i have updated ruby version from 2.3.1 to 3.0.1

Comment: It's just that you've jumped over a *lot* of Rails versions and consequent changes and deprecations, and I've seen quite a few posts about Paperclip over the years as Rails has changed. It might have been useful to see which Rails version broke your Paperclip code. I'm afraid I can't help with Paperclip specifically, though. Fingers crossed someone comes along who can!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an error.
paperclip io_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb file having function link_or_copy_file in that one log is there.

```
 def link_or_copy_file(src, dest)
  begin
    Paperclip.log("Trying to link #{src} to #{dest}")
    FileUtils.ln(src, dest, force: true) # overwrite existing
  rescue Errno::EXDEV, Errno::EPERM, Errno::ENOENT, Errno::EEXIST => e
    Paperclip.log(
      "Link failed with #{e.message}; copying link #{src} to #{dest}"
    )
    FileUtils.cp(src, dest)
  end

  @destination.close
  @destination.open.binmode
end
```

It's only log, file is uploading in local folder.